# Add a axis separately in "layout" with two graphs

Tags: r

Im trying to make these graphs look nice. I want to add the axis separately to be able to make the graphs in the same size. But how do I do this in a good way? When I try to create an y-axis it only goes from 0-1, even if I have made other settings. And how do I add ylab text to just a separate y-axis? And I would like the y-axis to be closer to the first graph, but I cant make the width smaller than 0.3, then there will be "Figure margins to large", how could I make the axis closer? Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
a <- rnorm(50,0,1)
b <- rnorm(50,0,1)
par(mar=c(2,2,2,2))
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
layout(mat = matrix(c(1, 2, 3), 
                    nrow = 1, 
                    ncol = 3),
       heights = c(1, 1, 1),    # Heights of the two rows
       widths = c(0.3, 2, 2))     # Widths of the two columns

par(mar=c(2,4,2,0))
plot.new()
axis(2, seq((-3), 3, 0.5), ylab="GGG")
par(mar=c(0,2,2,2))

barplot(sort(a), main="a", ylab="",cex.main=0.9, ylim=c(-3,3),yaxt='n')
par(mar=c(0,2,2,2))

barplot(sort(b), main="b", ylab="",cex.main=0.9, ylim=c(-3,3),yaxt='n')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the axis closer, you may use the `line=` option of the `axis` function, where you also can define negative values. In `axis` you need to define `at=` which positions ticks should appear; `axTicks(2)` is a nice helper that comes with R, and outputs the values with which the preceeding `*plot` function had drawn it's tickmarks.

To write the axis label you may use `mtext` where you define side and line, similar to `axis`.

I see no benefits to use `layout` here, so I omitted that. Note, that you may store the old par using assignment `op <-`, to use it to restore the default `par`s later.

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(1, 2), mar=c(2,4,2,1))

barplot(sort(a), main="a", ylab="", cex.main=0.9, ylim=c(-3,3), yaxt='n')
axis(2, at=axTicks(2), line=-.1)
mtext("GGG", 2, 2)
barplot(sort(b), main="b", ylab="",cex.main=0.9, ylim=c(-3,3),yaxt='n')

par(op)
```

### Result

[image]

### Update

To get both plots even closer, we may use a trick: `c`oncatenate both vectors, with a `NA` sequence between of length `adj`, then plot in one single `barplot`. To get the label positions `a` and `b` accurate, we use text and calculate `x` and `y` coordinates with an algorithm that uses the invisible output `p <-` of `barplot`.

```
adj <- 3

p <- barplot(c(sort(a), rep(NA, adj),  sort(b)), main="", ylab="", cex.main=0.9, 
             ylim=c(-3,3), xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
axis(2, at=axTicks(2), line=-.1)
mtext("GGG", 2, 2)
text(c(mean(p[1:length(a)]), mean(p[(length(a) + adj):length(p)])), max(axTicks(2)), 
     labels=c("a", "b"), xpd=TRUE, font=2)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)  ## always use a seed for sake of reproducibility
a <- rnorm(50,0,1)
b <- rnorm(50,0,1)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! But now the graphs gets too far away from each other, I want them to be closer. If I change to par(mar=c(2,0,2,1)) for the second graph, then the graphs are in different sizes. How could this be solved?

Comment: @user11916948 Please note, that I've updated the label algorithm to be really "accurate"! :D